# jquery ajax pagination stops working after 2nd click

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

I am currently working on some ajax pagination. Here is my code behind it:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

$('#content').on('click', '.navigation a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');

    $('#content').fadeOut(200, function () {
        $(this).load(link + ' #content', function () {
            $(this).fadeIn(200);

            if ($("#content > div#content").length > 0) {
                $("#content > div#content").unwrap();
            }

        });
    });
});});
```

this works great for the first 2 pages. After the second page the jquery element stops working and defaults back to the normal pagination?

Can anyone see why this would be?

Comment: whats the problem with e.preventDefault?

Answer (score 0):

Unless this code is within `<script>` tags included in what is loaded into `#content`, what will happen is that the links in the dynamically loaded content will not have the click-binding.

You might need to re-apply the click binding:

```
$(...).load(..., function() {
    // ... 
    $('#content').on('click', ...
});
```

Of course, then you must define a suitable function to bind. Otherwise you need to write the same code again...

A bit hackish, in pseudo code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    function myPaginator (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr('href');

        $('#content').fadeOut(200, function () {
            $(this).load(link + ' #content', function () {
                $(this).fadeIn(200);

                if ($("#content > div#content").length > 0) {
                    $("#content > div#content").unwrap();
                }
                $('#content').on('click', '.navigation a', myPaginator);
            });
        });
    });

    $('#content').on('click', '.navigation a', myPaginator); 

});
```

Comment: the above js is wrapped in <script> tags. could you edit this fiddle to show what you mean please? http://jsfiddle.net/MAtkC/